# How to integrate multiple programming languages (VB, Java, Python)?

Tags: python, java, vb.net

For the development of an image processing tool I coded 2 programs, one in Java and another in Python. Both programs work independently but must be executed and called from a Visual Basic GUI. How would I go about calling/executing java and python code using visual basic?
Is there any way of doing this that is not just making .EXEs of the Java and Python code and starting a subprocess from VB?

Comment: one crazy idea is to embed both java and python into two c++ dlls that VB can call, but that's well beyond my programming ability, and would likely take a few weeks just to set the dlls up.

Comment: The .exe route is by far the easiest if each .exe would be able to get all the info it needs to run from the command line.  The alternative would be to package them into dlls (it should be a C interface rather than a C++ interface to be easy to call from .NET) but that may well be more complicated on the Python and Java side, especially ensuring that argument specs are consistent.